# QUrl does not parse host name with underscore

Tags: qt, url

Today I found that in Qt 4.6, QUrl would not parse a url if the host name contains the underscore.

I understand that according to the standard, underscore is not allowed in the domain name, however, there ARE some urls with underscores, especially for some subdomain.

For example, i came across this feed's url:

http://hero_hki.mysinablog.com/rss.php

and QUrl("http://hero_hki.mysinablog.com/rss.php").toString() returns "http:/rss.php"

Firefox and Google Chrome can access this page anyway.

(I tested with Qt 4.6 tp1. Not so sure whether this issue is fixed in the release, cuz I did not have time to compile the release version on my laptop for developing my toy feed reader.)

Any advice? Thanks :)

Comment: Tested it with Qt 4.6.0 release and the output is the same. However, Qt 4.3.4 outputs the URL correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the following from [Qt 4.6.0 changelog](http://qt.nokia.com/developer/changes/changes-4.6.0):

> QUrl's parser is more strict when for hostnames in URLs. QUrl now enforces STD 3 rules:
>
> - each individual hostname section (between dots) must be at most
>      63 ASCII characters in length;
> - only letters, digits, and the hyphen character are allowed in the
>      ASCII range; letters outside the ASCII range follow the normal
>      IDN rules
>
> That means QUrl no longer accepts some URLs that were invalid
>   before, but weren't interpreted as such.

Comment: Did not notice this changelog. It could be understood to follow the rules. I am even surprised that no other applications follow this strict way. And yes, mysinablog is unprofessional to allow this subdomain name, a headache for me now.